# Prince of Persia Level 3 - Making the jump

Tags: snes, prince-of-persia

I'm having difficulties making the big jump across the gap in level 3 the SNES version of Prince of Persia

This is just after hitting the switch on the top floor. I then run back jumping over gaps

On the final jump, I'm trying to pass through a gate before it closes. This is a really big gap and there is a breaking tile at the end.

Below it is a guillotine

Whenever I try to make that jump I die

Does anyone know how to jump it?

Answer (score 2):

You need perfect timing. Once you step on pressure plate in the East (right). The gate in the West will open up. Now make run for it. There is a collapsible tile in the gate screen. That's the tile from where your prince should jump. Now when that jump is made hold the **shift key** that should make him catch the tile inside the door. Then press up to climb . And you can go through the door.

Edit:-

The shift key was for the PC version. There should be one of the equivalent key on your SNES console.